# Finding the only pair in a sorted array A whose sum is equal to K

Tags: algorithm

I know this question has been asked so much times. However, after digging throughout all related posts on StackOverflow, I still don't find the deterministic answer. Can you help?

My question is that for such a problem, does a O(log n) solution exists? To make the problem even more clear, we can study two cases, respectively: case (1) A doesn't have duplicate and case (2) A has duplicate elements.

I heard a binary search based solution seem to be able to achieve a O(log n), but don't understand how it does. Here n is the number of elements in A.

Comment: How do you know there is only one such pair?

Comment: If (2) is the case, then your whole initial premise does not apply any more (that the array only has exactly one pair of elements that sum up to K).

Comment: @CBroe: It *could* still apply, as long as none of the dupes forms part of the sum you care about.

Comment: do you search 2 elements in the array that sum up to K or is it an array of pairs? because for the second case it is not really clear how it should be sorted.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose element i has the value 2i for every position except one position where it has value 2i+1.

If the target is a value 2n+1, then we will have to test every pair of i and n-i until we find the position with 2i+1.

Therefore it will be impossible to do better than O(n) in both your cases.

Comment: You are assuming that finding a match for `i` is an O(N) operation.  However, since the array is sorted, a binary search allows a match to be found in O(ln N)

Comment: @JamesCurran I am claiming that the complete algorithm to find any match cannot do better than O(n) (this is not just the time for a match for a single element).  Your suggested method takes O(nlogn).  I think it is also possible to have a method that takes O(n) (by having a pointer to the start and the end that move towards each other).  However I claim that no one will be able to beat O(n).

Comment: will a binary search in {A[i]+A[i+1] | i = 0,1,..., n - 2} help?

Answer (score 1):

Forget what I said before.  Since it a *sorted* array, we can do this in **O(N)**.

- Add the *first* and *last* elements. If they equal `K`, done. If sum is greater that `K`, Add the first & *second to last*. If sum is less than `k`, Add the *second* and the last.
- Repeat working into the middle until a correct sum is found, or you meet in the middle.

Comment: Under certain conditions this algorithm can be modified to allow for faster searching that is still worst case O(N), but best case is (Big Theta)(log N). For example in the case of k = 200 and you have a list of say range(1-50) + range(150-1000), using an exponentially increasing (rather than linearly increasing) offset would allow for skipping from 1 to 50 and 1000 to 150 in O(log(50) + log(1000-150)) steps, which would be O(log N) steps, resulting in the better lower bounds. Though the worst case gets a somewhat higher hidden constant factor using that approach.

Answer (score 0):

Create an empty HashSet  (O(ln n) lookup)

Iterate through array, for each number `n`, check the HashSet for `K-n`. If found, your done., if not found, add `n` to the hashSet.  (iteration is O(N))

Total O(N ln N)